# How can I add recipient on bitcoind CLI

Tags: bitcoind, script, linux, multi-signature

I know I can add recipients to a transaction on bitcoin-qt and I am looking for a similar way to do it on bitcoind CLI on linux and in bash script.

I tried using createrawtransaction and multi-sig but with no avail, I'm probably missing something, can someone enlighten me?